# SAML authentication with client certificate but without user interaction using ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2

Tags: saml-2.0, ws-trust, itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I need to call a SOAP webservice using SAML authentication. 
They expect the saml token as part of the SOAP request(This should not be a problem).

The actual authentication on the IDP must be done using a client certificate (private key), but without any user interaction. 
As far as i understand are the samples on https://www.itfoxtec.com/IdentitySaml2 are based on browser based redirection authentication.

Question: Is it possible to authenticate on an IDP via client certificate without user interaction using the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library? 
If yes, could you point me in the direction of how to do this, or is there even a sample for such a use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible to authenticate on an IdP via a client certificate without user interaction using the ITfoxtec.Identity.Saml2 library. The library support SAML 2.0 and SAML 2.0 profile (browser based redirect/post login and logout).

Inested you need to use WS-Trust and SAML 2.0 which is supported by .NET.